# How to train an efficiently updatable neural network (NNUE)?

Tags: engines, analysis, programming, evaluation

I've been working on my own chess engine for a while now. It uses standard minimax search. I've trained a convolutional neural network as a static evaluation function, and I've had some good results with it. However recently I decided to learn more about NNUE. I've managed to implement it in my engine, and in terms of speed it is about 20 times faster than the conv net. However, i am having trouble with the accuracy of the network. It performs very poorly and doesn't generalize well, even though it has more parameters than the conv network.
Here are the details of both networks:

Model: "CONV"

| Layer (type) | Output Shape | Param |
| --- | --- | --- |
| input_1 (InputLayer) | [(None, 8, 8, 12)] | 0 |
| conv2d (Conv2D) | (None, 4, 4, 768) | 231168 |
| conv2d_1 (Conv2D) | (None, 2, 2, 384) | 2654592 |
| conv2d_2 (Conv2D) | (None, 1, 1, 192) | 295104 |
| flatten (Flatten) | (None, 192) | 0 |
| dense (Dense) | (None, 96) | 18528 |
| output_layer (Dense) | (None, 1) | 97 |

Total params: 3,199,489

Trainable params: 3,199,489

Non-trainable params: 0

---

Model: "NNUE"

| Layer (type) | Output Shape | Param | Connected to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stm_perspective (InputLayer) | [(None, 40960)] | 0 | [] |
| nstm_perspective (InputLayer) | [(None, 40960)] | 0 | [] |
| dense_1 (Dense) | (None, 255) | 10445055 | ['stm[0][0]', 'nstm[0][0]'] |
| concatenate (Concatenate) | (None, 510) | 0 | ['dense_1[0][0]', 'dense_1[1][0]'] |
| dense_2 (Dense) | (None, 32) | 16352 | ['concatenate[0][0]'] |
| dense_3 (Dense) | (None, 32) | 1056 | ['dense_2[0][0]'] |
| output_layer (Dense) | (None, 1) | 33 | ['dense_3[0][0]'] |

Total params: 10,462,496

Trainable params: 10,462,496

Non-trainable params: 0

---

The features of the conv network are (square_x, square_y, piece), and the nnue network uses the halfkp feature set. Both networks are trained on a dataset of positions with their evaluations normalized between 0 and 1. The conv net is trained on about 160M positions. I've stopped the training of the nnue net at 72M because it doesn't seem to improve anymore.

On the same positions, here are the mean squared error of the two neural networks:

NNUE: 0.1829

CONV: 0.0374

Does anybody know what could be going wrong here? I find it stange that a network with more parameters performs worse than a network with less parameters. Am I doing something wrong? Is the nnue net lacking training data? Or is it normal that conv nets perform so much better?

I can provide more details if needed. Thank you in advance!